# search item in hibernate query (select two tables)

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

Im having a trouble with my code. i have a view jsp where i can view all items. 
[image]

When i try to search for a name. It will loop or have a redundancy. I dont know why. looks like this.
[image]

BTW i have two tables and a foreign key product[pid] to stock[pid]

```
public class Product {

@Id
@Column(name="p_id")
private String pid;

@Column(name="p_name")
private String p_name;


@Column(name="c_name")
private String c_name;

@Column(name="b_name")
private String b_name; 
//SETTERS & GETTERS

public class Stock {

    @Id
    @Column(name="s_id")
    private int sid;

    @Column(name="p_id")
    private String pid;

    @Column(name="s_quantity")
    private String squantity;

    @Column(name="s_price")
    private String sprice;

    @Column(name="s_cost")
    private String cost;
//SETTERS AND GETTERS
```

@Controller

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/searchItem")
public String searchItem(HttpServletRequest request, ModelMap map, 
        @RequestParam(value = "page", required = false) Integer page,
        @RequestParam(value = "size", required = false) Integer size ) {


    String searchProductName = request.getParameter("productName");
    String cat = request.getParameter("category");
    String bran = request.getParameter("brand");

    Product searchProduct = new Product();


    searchProduct.setP_name(searchProductName);
    searchProduct.setC_name(cat);
    searchProduct.setB_name(bran);

    int pageSize = (size != null && size != 0) ? size : 25;
    int firstResultIndex = (page != null && page > 0) ? (page - 1) * pageSize : 0;
    List<Product> productList = catService.getUsers(searchProduct, firstResultIndex, pageSize);
    map.addAttribute("productList", productList);

    List<Category> cList = catService.getCat();
    map.addAttribute("cList", cList);
    List<Brand> bList = catService.getBrand();
    map.addAttribute("bList", bList);

    return "new/list";

}
```

@DaoImpl

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Override
public List<Product> getUsers(Product searchProduct, int startPage, int maxResults) {
    EntityManager entityManager = transactionManager.getEntityManagerFactory().createEntityManager();
Session session = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);

SQLQuery query = session.createSQLQuery("FROM product,stock");
        boolean paramExists = false;

    if (!StringUtility.isStringNullOrEmpty(searchProduct.getC_name())&&!StringUtility.isStringNullOrEmpty(searchProduct.getB_name()))  {
        //sqlQuerySB.append(" product.c_name LIKE :category AND product.b_name LIKE :brand");
     query = session.createSQLQuery("FROM product,stock WHERE product.c_name LIKE :category AND product.b_name LIKE :brand");
        paramExists = true;
    }


    if (!StringUtility.isStringNullOrEmpty(searchProduct.getP_name())) {

query = session.createSQLQuery("SELECT product.p_name,product.c_name,product.b_name,stock.s_quantity,stock.s_price,stock.s_cost FROM product,stock WHERE product.p_name LIKE :productName");

query.setParameter("productName", "%" + searchProduct.getP_name() + "%");
            paramExists = true;

    }

    if (!StringUtility.isStringNullOrEmpty(searchProduct.getC_name())) {

        query = session.createSQLQuery("SELECT product.p_name,product.c_name,product.b_name,stock.s_quantity,stock.s_price,stock.s_cost FROM product,stock WHERE product.c_name LIKE :category ");
        query.setParameter("category", "" + searchProduct.getC_name() + "");
            paramExists = true;

    }

    query.setResultTransformer(Criteria.ALIAS_TO_ENTITY_MAP);

    List<Product> productList = query.list();

    if (entityManager.isOpen())
        entityManager.close();

    return productList;
}
```

maybe there is a big problem in my DAOimpl on how i query two tables..
need some help/advice. ty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not specifying the join criteria between product and stock:

```
SELECT 
    product.p_name,
    product.c_name,
    product.b_name,
    stock.s_quantity,
    stock.s_price,
    stock.s_cost 
FROM product, stock 
WHERE product.p_name LIKE :productName
```

In this case it will return one row for each for each combination of product (with the name) and stock (full table since it does not have any criteria).

Try to specify the join criteria:

```
SELECT 
    product.p_name,
    product.c_name,
    product.b_name,
    stock.s_quantity,
    stock.s_price,
    stock.s_cost 
FROM product, stock 
WHERE 
product.pid = stock.pid
product.p_name LIKE :productName
```